# AADB2C90289: We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, okta

I am trying to set up OKTA as an external identity provider in Azure B2C with custom policies. When I try to sign in, I receive the following error

> AADB2C90289: We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider.
> Please try again later.
>
> Correlation ID: xxx
> Timestamp: 2021-10-14 16:53:12Z

I have followed this tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy.

I also followed a number of articles on this but no concrete solution anywhere.

Comment: 99% of the time this is due to incorrect secret provided to AAD B2C policy keys from Okta, or incorrect policy key referenced in your custom policy.